# Introduce Arrows in tree layout d3

Tags: d3.js

I have to implement a tree layout as in http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/parent-foci.html

And which should have arrows from parent to child or in some cases arrow should point from child to parent also ...
as in http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/ncwuej9j/

```
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

Looks like this is used for arrow .But I am unable to figure howw to use in tree layout.

Have understood that json format is different for both ... If this is possible.
I am new to D3 , so guys help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the code you shared, the only thing you need to put an arrow at the end of the paths is adding an `marker-end` on the paths:

```
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

For instance, taking this tree layout from d3noob: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8326869 . It has no arrows, as you can easily check. So, let's add them.

The first step is appending the `defs`, as you shared:

```
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
.data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
.enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
.attr("id", String)
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", 15)
.attr("refY", -1.5)
.attr("markerWidth", 6)
.attr("markerHeight", 6)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("svg:path")
.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

Then, at the end of the paths (change this according to your real code, which you didn't provide):

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", diagonal)
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
  
update(root);

function update(source) {

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 18)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("y", function(d) { 
    return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", diagonal)
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

}
```

```css
 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What a neat way of accessing the bound data by providing the global `String` object as a replacement for the `function(d) { return d; }`. Similarly, this will even work for the notorious string-to-number conversions by passing in `Number`. I have never thought about that before. You live and learn!